# NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate: how to to populate right side popup

Tags: cocoa, nspredicate, nspredicateeditor, nsexpression

I am trying to generate an `NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate` that on the left side has a number of property names from an entity *Foo*, among which is the property *bar*. When the user selects '*bar*', the right side should become popup which contains all values of '*bar*'.

How can I best populate the right side popup? All unique values of *bar* are stored in an `NSMutableArray`, so perhaps I can use KVO to change the row template when the array changes.

Is there a way that I can use code to easily change the values in a right side popup in an `NSPredicateEditor` row? I can enter a few static values in IB, but that will not do in this situation.

**EDIT**

Having read a good deal of related Q&A's, including [NSPredicateEditor in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642681/nspredicateeditor-in-xcode-4) and the excellent answer to it by @Dave DeLong, I think a good bit of the work can be done like this:

```
NSArray *leftexp = @[[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"name"],[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"married"]];
NSArray *rightexp = @[[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"One"],[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"Two"]];
NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate *template = [[NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate alloc] initWithLeftExpressions:leftexp rightExpressions:rightexp modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier operators:@[@(NSEqualToPredicateOperatorType)] options:0];

NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate *compound = [[NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate alloc] initWithCompoundTypes:@[@(NSOrPredicateType)]];

[self.predicateEditor setRowTemplates:@[template,compound]];
NSEntityDescription *description = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
self.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == ''"];
```

I've seen a few ways to make the basic NSPredicateEditor appear (with at least the compound line), but it seems to me that there has to be an elegant way to do that, the way it was *meant* to be done. Can't find that though, can anyone help me along with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some would probably argue that the way it is *meant* to be done is in Interface Builder.  That would probably be fine if you're familiar with how row templates work, how they get combined, etc.  Personally, I prefer to create the programmatically because I can be explicit about how the row templates function.

Let's go through an example of how this all works together, and then you can decide which approach works best for you:

- You have an object with two `NSString` properties: `bar` and `baz`
- `bar` can only have a certain number of possible values, which we'll call `@"Bar1"`, `@"Bar2"`, and `@"Bar3"`.
- `baz` can be any `NSString` value.

With this in mind, here's how you'd create that programmatically:

```
// these defines are for brevity on the web page; please don't actually do this
#define NSPERT NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate
#define KP(_kp) [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:(_kp)]
#define CV(_cv) [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:(_cv)]

NSPERT *compound = [[NSPERT alloc] initWithCompoundTypes:@[@(NSAndPredicateType), 
                                                           @(NSOrPredicateType), 
                                                           @(NSNotPredicateType)]];

NSPERT *bar = [[NSPERT alloc] initWithLeftExpressions:@[KP(@"bar")] 
                                     rightExpressions:@[CV(@"Bar1"), CV(@"Bar2"), CV(@"Bar3")] 
                                             modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier 
                                            operators:@[@(NSEqualToPredicateOperatorType), 
                                                        @(NSNotEqualToPredicateOperatorType)] 
                                              options:0];

NSPERT *baz = [[NSPERT alloc] initWithLeftExpressions:@[KP(@"baz")] 
                         rightExpressionAttributeType:NSStringAttributeType 
                                             modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier 
                                            operators:@[@(NSEqualToPredicateOperatorType),
                                                        @(NSNotEqualToPredicateOperatorType)]
                                              options:0];

NSArray *templates = @[compound, bar, baz];
[self.myPredicateEditor setRowTemplates:templates];
```

---

Granted, this is a lot of typing just to create row templates.  I understand that.  I just think that it's also very explicit and easy to debug.  That being said, you can also configure this exact same thing in Interface Builder.  To do so, put an `NSPredicateEditor` in your xib, and give it 3 row templates.  The Compound row template you'd leave alone, but the other two you'd change to be configured like this:

For the "`bar`" template:

[image: "Bar" row template configuration]

For the "`baz`" template:

[image: "Baz" row template configuration]

If you compare these screenshots to the code above, it should (hopefully) be easy to see how one maps to the other.  With the row templates configured like this, IB also shows the predicate editor in your window:

[image: Window with predicate editor]

If you want to do more advanced things, such as creating custom row templates, or populating the list of allowed constant values with something from your data model, then you'll have to drop to doing the configuration in code.

---

**Edit to answer comment question**

The `modifier` bit of these selectors corresponds to the [`NSComparisonPredicateModifer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSComparisonPredicate_Class/Reference/NSComparisonPredicate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001189-BBCJDIJH) for the created `NSComparisonPredicate`.  There are three modifiers: Direct, Any, and All.

```
@"bar = 'Bar1'";
  ^ No modifier means this is NSDirectPredicateModifier

@"ANY user.userName = 'markjs'";
  ^~~ use of "ANY" keyword means this is NSAnyPredicateModifier

@"ALL user.age < 42";
  ^~~ use of "ALL" keyword means this is NSAllPredicateModifier
```

In these three examples, they're all comparison predicates (because they have a left side, an operator, and a right side), but the use of "ANY" or "ALL" affects how the left side is interpreted.  If either is present, then the predicate is expecting the left-hand side to evaluate to a collection of possibilities.

Using the "direct" option (or `0`) basically means you're going to be doing a one-to-one comparison.

Comment: Thanks again for good info on one of those classes in Cocoa that I like a lot but find very difficult to understand at the same time. Using IB makes it hard (impossible?), I think, to change the right-side constants during runtime. Or is there some binding that I could use? Secondly, do you have a link with information about the `modifier:` variable in these methods? Can't find anything on google or even SO!

Comment: @markjs You can *maybe* find a way to dynamically change an IB-generated row template at runtime (I can't think of a way offhand to do this), but I think making that row template programmatically would be *much* simpler.  Also, I added a bit at the end about the modifier :)

Comment: Thanks again! I have a nicely functional predicate editor now. One of the strangest things I have found is that there really must be an `NSPredicate` associated with the editor, through `-setObjectValue:`. Empty window if there isn't!

Comment: If the user removes the last "real" predicate, the compound line also disappears. At which point no new row can be added! I looked into `NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate` if there is a way to prevent the user from using the "remove" button, but no luck. Do I need a custom template (hope not)?

Comment: @markjs check out the "Can remove all rows" check box in IB (or `setCanRemoveAllRows:`).  You want that to be "NO", at which point the editor will remove the `-` button if only one row is left (which if you allow compounding, will be the compound row).

Comment: @markjs You could also have a button that just calls `-addRow:` on the editor, but usually the "can remove all rows" thing is what you want.

Comment: This worked out great! I now try to store the sometimes complex predicates using core data, but am having great trouble getting the `NSPredicateEditor` to play nicely with the `NSArrayController` (at least, I think that's where the problem lies). The issue is described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586867/crash-with-nspredicateeditor-value-bound-to-selection-from-an-nsarraycontroller because it would be too long here. Any thoughts would bbs greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The key to filling an `NSPredicateEditor` with a compound row (NOT, AND, OR), as well as one row with a simple predicate, is that the `NSPredicateEditor` should receive a `-setRowTemplates:` call with an `NSArray` that contains both the compound, and the regular predicate. Then, its predicate should be set to a *compound* predicate with a subpredicate, using `-andPredicateWithSubpredicates:`.

This did the trick for me:

```
NSArray *leftexp = @[[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"name"]];
NSArray *rightexp = @[[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:@"A"],[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:@"B"],[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:@"C"]];
NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate *template = [[NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate alloc] \
          initWithLeftExpressions:leftexp
          rightExpressions:rightexp
          modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier
          operators:@[@(NSEqualToPredicateOperatorType)]
          options:0];
NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate *compound = [[NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate alloc] initWithCompoundTypes:@[@(NSAndPredicateType),@(NSOrPredicateType),@(NSNotPredicateType)]];
NSMutableArray *templates = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:compound];
[templates addObject:template];
[self.predicateEditor setRowTemplates:templates];

NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == 'A'"];
self.predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObject:p]];
```

Comment: And thanks Dave for some great answers elsewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642681/nspredicateeditor-in-xcode-4 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976244/forcing-the-display-of-a-compound-row-with-nspredicateeditor?rq=1 !

Comment: +1 good for you for figuring this out!  Predicate editors took me a long time to grok.

Answer (score 1):

Bassed on markjs answer, I translated it to swift 4 and placed it in a extension of NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate.

```
extension NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate {

    convenience init( compoundTypes: [NSCompoundPredicate.LogicalType] ) {

        var compoundTypesNSNumber: [NSNumber] = []
        for c in compoundTypes { compoundTypesNSNumber.append( NSNumber(value: c.rawValue) ) }
        self.init( compoundTypes: compoundTypesNSNumber )
    }

    convenience init( forKeyPath keyPath: String, withValues values: [Any] ) {

        let keyPaths: [NSExpression] = [NSExpression(forKeyPath: keyPath)]

        var constantValues: [NSExpression] = []
        for v in values {

            constantValues.append( NSExpression(forConstantValue: v) )
        }

        let operators: [NSComparisonPredicate.Operator] = [.equalTo, .notEqualTo]
        var operatorsNSNumber: [NSNumber] = []
        for o in operators { operatorsNSNumber.append( NSNumber(value: o.rawValue) ) }

        self.init( leftExpressions: keyPaths,
                   rightExpressions: constantValues,
                   modifier: .direct,
                   operators: operatorsNSNumber,
                   options: (Int(NSComparisonPredicate.Options.caseInsensitive.rawValue | NSComparisonPredicate.Options.diacriticInsensitive.rawValue)) )
    }

    convenience init( stringCompareForKeyPaths keyPaths: [String] ) {

        var leftExpressions: [NSExpression] = []
        for keyPath in keyPaths {

            leftExpressions.append( NSExpression(forKeyPath: keyPath) )
        }

        let operators: [NSComparisonPredicate.Operator] = [.contains, .equalTo, .notEqualTo, .beginsWith, .endsWith]
        var operatorsNSNumber: [NSNumber] = []
        for o in operators { operatorsNSNumber.append( NSNumber(value: o.rawValue) ) }

        self.init( leftExpressions: leftExpressions,
                   rightExpressionAttributeType: .stringAttributeType,
                   modifier: .direct,
                   operators: operatorsNSNumber,
                   options: (Int(NSComparisonPredicate.Options.caseInsensitive.rawValue | NSComparisonPredicate.Options.diacriticInsensitive.rawValue)) )
    }

    convenience init( IntCompareForKeyPaths keyPaths: [String] ) {

        var leftExpressions: [NSExpression] = []
        for keyPath in keyPaths {

            leftExpressions.append( NSExpression(forKeyPath: keyPath) )
        }

        let operators: [NSComparisonPredicate.Operator] = [.equalTo, .notEqualTo, .greaterThan, .greaterThanOrEqualTo, .lessThan, .lessThanOrEqualTo]
        var operatorsNSNumber: [NSNumber] = []
        for o in operators { operatorsNSNumber.append( NSNumber(value: o.rawValue) ) }

        self.init( leftExpressions: leftExpressions,
                   rightExpressionAttributeType: .integer16AttributeType,
                   modifier: .direct,
                   operators: operatorsNSNumber,
                   options: 0 )
    }
}
```

Uses it follows:

```
   func setMyPetFilter() {

        // We assume that myPredicateEditor is create/set in IB
        // Remove whatever was configured in IB
        myPredicateEditor.rowTemplates.removeAll()

        let templateCompoundTypes = NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate( compoundTypes: [.and, .or, .not] )
        let template1 = NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate( forKeyPath: "Animals", withValues: ["Dog", "Cat", "Hamster", "Canary"] )
        let template2 = NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate( stringCompareForKeyPaths: ["PetName", "OwnerName"] )
        let template3 = NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate( forKeyPath: "Legs", withValues: [2,4] )
        let template4 = NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate( IntCompareForKeyPaths: ["Age", "AgeOwner"] )
        myPredicateEditor.rowTemplates = [templateCompoundTypes, template1, template2, template3, template4]
    }
```